# How to download a folder from FTP server

Tags: android

I successfully downloaded single file from FTP server to my SD card by giving URL.But iam unable to download a folder which contains 30 files(.jpg,.flv,etc.,) from FTP server.so please help me some code, how to download an entire folder from FTP server to SD card.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Android sdk doesnt have built-in function to download entire folder from ftp. it has to be download one file at a time, and create the folder(s) from your app.

If you're using FTP, you could use the FTP classes in [Apache commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/).

You can try to get download all files at once using a list of files.You can issue a LIST command, but the results are not standardized. Your server should generate a manifest (whose name is known) and/or you could use an FTP library

Comment: By using FTPClient from commons-net library,iam unable to connect to FTP server.so i tried in a simply way just downloaded by giving the path(URL).Could u please help me that how to use that LIST command from FTP library...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily using the Ftp.downloadDir method available in Secure FTP Factory library.  This is a commercial library but handles all of the overhead of this process nicely.

http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-ftp-factory/